# What does the term "slow drift" mean?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, drift

Good night everyone. I came across the term "slow drift" when reading a paper on an electronic design, and I am not quite sure what it means. The author said he used a low pass amplifier to remove slow-drift to the non-inverting input to an operational amplifier. What exactly is he saying?

Comment: Now I'm curious about this article -- it sounds fishy.

Comment: @Jason S - This article is describing the design of an electronic device that measures blood oxygen concentration and heart beat rate (http://www.engedu2.net/v1/HS-T13.pdf)

Comment: Ah -- that explains it, the author said he used a *high pass filter* to remove slow drift. That makes more sense.

Comment: Also the slow drift in this case refers to the photodiode output (whether caused by slow changes in the diode itself or the driver LED or the transfer function between the two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Slow Drift" means Change in the value of the parameter without any external change
or
change in output even though the input was provided.

Due to this the stability of the circuit will be loss or decreased  and degrades its performance.

You can find this drift mostly in the Oscillators.

In Op-Amps, The low pass filter was used at the non-inverting input in order to
compensate the drift and get stability.

How to reduce the drift in op-amps?
A: [Chopper-stabilized op-amp](https://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/chopper-stabilized-op-amps). This set-up uses a normal op-amp with an additional AC amplifier.
This is one method to reduce the drift in the op-Amps.  and there are various methods to reduce drift.

Comment: How do you determine the amount of drift? Is it in the spec sheets or is there a certain method used to measure it?

Comment: @DBrown:Go through the answer which was edited as per your request

Answer (score 5):

Drift in general refers to a parameter that changes slowly.  In this case, the parameter is the input offset voltage of the opamp.  A ideal opamp amplifies the voltage difference between the positive and negative inputs:

Out = Gain(Pin - Nin)

Real opamps have a little error in when they see the positive and negative inputs being equal:

Out = Gain(Pin - Nin + Err)

This error value can drift over time and temperature, which is what the paper was referring to.

Note that this offset voltage results in a DC output error.  A step change in (Pin-Nin) will still result in the same size output step.  This property is the basis for *chopper stabilized* amplifiers.  Basically the input voltage is fed in as a sequence of steps, and the resulting amplitude of the step changes used at the output.  Any slowly varying DC offset on those steps is therefore ignored.

In cases where your signal doesn't contain DC (like audio), a simple high pass filter will remove the offset.  Since the offset changes (drifts) very slowly, it can be thought of as very low frequency noise on the signal.  If the lowest meaningful frequency of your signal is well above that, then a high pass filter removes the DC drift.

Answer (score 1):

It helps when you provide context. The article you mention has essentially this system at its front end:

drive LED -> human finger -> photodiode -> high pass filter (tau=0.1second) -> gain of 100

The high pass filter is present to remove unpredictable DC and low-frequency values before amplifying the results, so that the x100 amplifier isn't saturated, or affected by slowly-changing parameters in the LED or photodiode or finger.